# Creating customisable "templates", for use within ReactJS components, without

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that looks something like this:

```
var MyTemplatedComponent = React.createClass({

  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      discountValue: '10% off',
      welcomeMessage: 'Want {{discountValue}} off your next order?'
    };
  },

  getWelcomeMessage: function () {
    return this.props.welcomeMessage.replace('{{discountValue}}', '<strong>'+this.props.discountValue+'</strong>');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <p className='lead' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.getWelcomeMessage() }} />
    );
  }

});
```

The goal is to allow our clients to customize the `{{discountValue}}` to suit their preferences. We then want to **bold** the discount value it when being rendered.

Currently the only way I've found of doing this correctly is using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it feels dangerous! And a little ugly.

Can anyone think of a better way of handling this?

Comment: Should the '{{welcomeMessage}}' in the `getWelcomeMessage()` function be '{{discountValue}}'?

Comment: And you want them to be able to customize both the welcome message and/or the discount value?

Comment: @DanielRobinson ah yes that was a typo - fixed. And yes the should be able to customize both. For this question assume the client will never remove the `{{discountValue}}` from inside `{{welcomeMessage}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dangerouslySetInnerHTML isn't that dangerous in this case (since the welcomeMessage would be written by the client). If you're concerned, though, that the client might mess it up and put user input into the welcome message, just escape the welcome message template before you start putting in HTML.

The following escape code is taken from [react itself](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/54c82da15f6b4717425edbf68e23ae82583a50af/src/utils/escapeTextForBrowser.js):

```
var ESCAPE_LOOKUP = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  '\'': '&#x27;'
};

var ESCAPE_REGEX = /[&><"']/g;

function escaper(match) {
  return ESCAPE_LOOKUP[match];
}

function escapeTextForBrowser(text) {
  return ('' + text).replace(ESCAPE_REGEX, escaper);
}
```

Once you have that function, you can fix the getWelcomeMessage function like so:

```
  getWelcomeMessage: function () {
    return escapeTextForBrowser(this.props.welcomeMessage).replace('{{discountValue}}', '<strong>'+this.props.discountValue+'</strong>');
  },
```